# inverse of adjacency list in O(|V | + |E|)

Tags: algorithm, big-o, adjacency-list, inverse

Let G = (V, E) be a directed graph, given in the adjacency list format. Define a
directed graph G' = (V, E') where an edge (u, v) ∈ E'
if and only if (v, u) ∈ E (namely, G'reverses the direction of each edge in G). Describe an algorithm to obtain an adjacency list representation
of G'
in O(|V | + |E|) time.

is there a simple way inverse the adjacency list?

**say if it was:**

```
a-> b
b-> de
c-> c
d-> ab
e->
```

**to:**

```
a-> d
b-> ad
c-> c
d-> ab
e-> b
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's say you iterate the adjacency lists of all vertices in the graph as follows.

```
for each u in V:
    for each v in adjacency_list[u]:
        reverse_adjacency_list[v].append(u)
```

With this approach, you traverse the adjacency lists of all |V| vertices, which contributes **O(|V|)** to the overall time complexity of your algorithm. Also, as you traverse every item in the adjacency list, **you effectively traverse all the edges in the graph**. In other words, if you concatenated all the individual lists (i.e., `adjacency_list[u]`) you traverse as part of the adjacency list, the length of that resulting list would be |E|. Thus, another **O(|E|)** is contributed to the overall complexity.

Consequently, the time complexity will be **O(|V| + |E|)** with this pretty standard approach, and you do not need to devise any peculiar method to achieve this complexity.